# WPF drag & drop events not getting through if drag target is obscured by other graphics

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, hittest

In the image below, there are 6 orange rectangles, which are acting as *drop targets*. The blue rectangles are in front of the orange rectangles. Both the blue and orange rectangles are children of the same container.

[image]

The problem I'm having is that the DragEnter, DragLeave, and Drop events are not getting triggered when the cursor is over a blue rectangle. The blue rectangle seems to be blocking the events from getting through to the orange rectangles. This means the user has to precisely position the cursor between the blue rectangles to be able to drop the item. I'd like to expand the drop area to include the entire orange rectangle, while still have the blue rectangles in front of the orange rectangles.

In case it's important, the orange rectangles are FrameworkElements, and the blue rectangles are DrawingVisuals. FrameworkElements have drag & drop capability, while DrawingVisuals are very bare-bones and do not.

How can I get the DragEnter, DragLeave, and Drop events for the orange rectangles to be triggered whenever the cursor is hovering them, regardless of whether the cursor is over a blue rectangle?

Comment: you could make the blue rectangles `IsHitTestVisible="False"` or do you need to intercept mouse events from the blue rects aswell?

Comment: @sa_ddam213 I tried that at some point, but `IsHitTestVisible` doesn't seem to be available for DrawingVisuals.

Comment: ahh, then perhaps use the `PreviewDragLeave` etc on the Orange rects

Comment: @sa_ddam213, interesting idea, but still doesn't work. I think because it's not a bubbling/tunneling issue, it's a hit test issue. The blue rectangle is not higher/lower in the visual tree, it's just a different z layer at the same level (i.e., orange is not a parent or child of blue).

Comment: Can you make a little sample xaml of your layout, So I can see.

Comment: @sa_ddam213, I can't do it right now, but if I don't get any answers, I'll try tomorrow. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742254.aspx, may help you out.

Answer (score 1):

The most reasonable solution I could come up with was to put the orange rectangles *on top* of the blue ones.

However, because I didn't want the orange rectangles to cover up the blue ones, I had to come up with a visual composed of a transparent rectangle plus an orange hat, as shown in this image:

[image]

So, here's how it works:

- The goal is to be able to change the order of the blue rectangles via drag & drop (in my real app, there can be more than three blue rectangles, and the blue rectangles are not really blue rectangles).
- Normally, only the blue rectangles and transparent rectangles are drawn. (Of course, the user only sees the blue rectangles.)
- If the user drags a blue rectangle, the orange hat appears if the cursor is over the transparent rectangle.
- Once the cursor leaves the transparent rectangle the orange hat disappears.
- After the blue rectangle is dropped, all the blue rectangles are redrawn in the new order (and the orange hats are once again hidden).